# GSPREAD: How do I fetch the last added worksheet from a spreadsheet having many worksheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Using gspread, I know how to access a sheet by name, id or index, like:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

worksheet = sh.worksheet("January")
```

or

```
worksheet = sh.sheet1
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to open a last added or last updated sheet?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the last modification of each spreadsheet sheet because this modification is fetched through Google Drive.

It's possible to obtain the last modification of the entire worksheet using the *lastUpdateTime*:

```py
import gspread
sa = gspread.service_account('authentication')
sa.open("worksheet name").lastUpdateTime
```